# How to set color of a row in Gtk2::TreeView Perl?

Tags: perl, gtk, gtk2, gtktreeview

I use TreeView and ListStore to show a GUI table. How can I set color a defined row? Are there any samples how to do it? With google I've found an example only for SimpleList, but I need it for ListStore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to set color on a TreeView.
The first is:
Set a column where color will be keep and then use method of TreeViewColumn "set_attributes" to set color of a cell renderer.

```
my $list_store = Gtk2::ListStore("Glib::String", "Glib::String"); # keep one note and color
my $tree_view = Gtk2::TreeView->new($list_store);
my $col = Gtk2::TreeViewColumn->new;
my $rend = Gtk2::CellRendererText->new;
$col->pack_start($rend, TRUE);
$col->set_attributes($rend,'text' => $i++, 'background' => 1,);
$tree_view->append_column($col);
```

---

And the second way is:
Do not use an additional column to keep a color but use method set_cell_data_func of TreeViewColumn:

```
$col->set_cell_data_func($rend, sub {
    my ($column, $cell, $model, $iter) = @_;        
    if ($model->get($iter, 0) eq 'Good') {  
        print "Red\n";
        $cell->set('background' => 'red');
    } else {
        $cell->set('background' => 'white');
    }
});
```